# Residue at $z_k=\frac{1}{k\pi}$ of function $f(z)=\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sin(1/z)}\right)$

Tags: complex-numbers

I neet to compute exactly the residue $f(z)=\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sin(1/z)}\right)$ at the singularities  $z_k=\frac{1}{k\pi}$ with $k\neq0$ (integer).
I know they are essential singularities.

Comment: Can you prove that the function $f(z)=\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sin(1/z)}\right)$ has essential singularities at $z_{k.k\not= 0}=\frac{1}{k\pi}$?

Comment: Yes, I take two sequences or complex number  $\{z_n\}_n$ and $\{w_n\}_n$ with $z_n\to \tfrac{1}{k\pi}$ and $w_n\to \tfrac{1}{k\pi}$ but  $f(z_n)=1$ and $f(w_n)=1/2$.

For example, if $k$ is even then I take

$z_n=\frac{1}{\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{\pi/2+2n\pi}\right)+k\pi}$

$w_n=\frac{1}{\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{\pi/6+2n\pi}\right)+k\pi}$

($\arcsin$ is the real function, inverse of $\sin$ in the domain $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.